# thread safe update of hashmap

Tags: java, thread-safety, hashmap

I have an `HashMap` as:

```
 Map<Integer ,ArrayList<Double>> map1 = new HasMap<Integer,ArrayList<Double>>()
```

This map is accessed and modified by some number of threads. I would like to make thread safe update for the granularity level of each of the component of `ArrayList`. It means, one value can be modified by several threads but one component can not be modified by several threads. How can I do it? Does this prevents from "undefined property" while iterating? [iterating values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29)

[EDIT]

```
 key      value
 1000    [0.1,0.002,0.8,0.112]
```

Each of the components of value is updated. While updating, first component can be updated by one thread and second by another thread at a time. I don't want to lock a  pair for one thread only.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "component" here vs "value".

Comment: It's unclear if you want to modify the Map or the ArrayList concurrently - or both.

Comment: Arraylist concurrently . Keys are not modified. Want to  update arraylist associated with each map

Comment: Each map? I can see only one Map in your example. So you don't add or remove ArrayList's to the Map concurrently?

Comment: there is collections of maps. But it is one to one map. Each key is associated with one value only.i am showing one key for an example only

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to use a [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).  When you call `lock()` It will allow you to "lock" the resource from being used by other threads, then call `unlock()` when the update is finished on that resource so that other threads can then modify it.  You can create a lock for each resource.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an ArrayList, use a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)  - it's designed especially for multi-threading and performs much better than variants which uses mutexes/synchronization (like `Vector`):

```
Map<Integer ,List<Double>> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, CopyOnWriteArrayList<Double>>();
```

(but beware if you do much more updates than reads to the List)

According do you comments, you don't need any synchronization of the outer `Map`, because it's not modified concurrently.

Comment: how to change granularity level of component of arraylist?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try with `ConcurrentHashMap` for this